# JQuery parent selector and fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple ToDo list in JQuery and I run into a problem.
I made function 'deleteListItem' and I use it to delete my lists items with:

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

, and then I wanted to add fadeOut effect to my list and so I tried:

```
$(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

, but this fadesOut just my delete button so then I tried

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

and this fades all of my 'ul' instead of just 'li' element.
Here is mine JSBIN so you better understand what I'm doing:  http://jsbin.com/ciyufi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the callback handler, `this` refers to the `<li>`.

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).remove();
})
```

Comment: That worked great. Thank you. So my mistake was using parent 2x and therefore using on my "ul" ?

Comment: Yes. Initially `$(this).parent()` is the `<li>`. So that was fading out appropriately. But inside the handler, `this` is now the `<li>`. So `$(this).parent()` is the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// This is where I put my functions

// This function adds items on our list
function addListItem() {
 var text=$('#newText').val();  // val returns any text thats inside input
 $('#todoList').append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="done">'+ text +'<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>');
 $('#newText').val(''); // this is added so that our input deletes previous text when add is clicked
};

// This function deletes items on our list
function deleteListItem() {
 // In order to delete entire list item we have to use parent method > without parent method we would only delete our delete button
 $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function(){
  $(this).closest("li").remove();
 })

};

// This function adds checked remark on our item list
function itemDone() { 
 // First we check if our element has textDecoration="line-through"
 // If it has it second line deletes it
 // And our else statement allows as to add it again
 if ($(this).parent().css('textDecoration') == 'line-through') {
  $(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'none');
 } else {
  $(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
 } 
}


$ (document).ready(function(){

 $('#add').on('click', addListItem); // This is for button to add text

 // This part enables us to add text on pressing enter key
 $( "#newText" ).keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13) {
   addListItem();
  }
 });

 // $('.delete').on('click', deleteListItem);
 // $('.done').on('click', itemDone);

 // Lines above don't work because we are adding elements after page loads
 // In above lines browser didn't bind functions to our new elements because it didn't see them at the time
 // In order to make it work we add document selector > its not the best solution but i'm not good enough for better 
 // We don't need to do it for #add because its already on page
 $(document).on('click', '.delete', deleteListItem);
 $(document).on('click', '.done', itemDone);





});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>ToDo Lista</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
 
<section class="container">
    <h1>ToDo List</h1>
    <ul id="todoList">
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="done"> Clean House <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="done">Buy Milk <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        <input id="newText" type="text" placeholder="Write Your Task"><button id="add">Add</button>
    </ul>
</section>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I prefer to use `closest`. [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) Just change 'deleteListItem' function to remove closest `li` item on delete.

```
function deleteListItem() {
    // In order to delete entire list item we have to use parent method > without parent method we would only delete our delete button
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $(this).closest("li").remove();
    })

};
```